# Taking the last 3 digits/character from a database table VB.NET

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

I am a newbie to vb.net and I was asked to make a program for our office (Equipment Monitoring).

Now here is my scenario:

I have a database table with a column/field named product_number(VARCHAR)
Now my supervisor wants it so that when she adds a new equipment, a product number will automatically be generated. It should be simple if only this product number consists only of numbers but here is its format: DOLE-IMSD-10-###

The last 3 digits/characters should be unique. Lets say the last product number was DOLE-IMSD-10-001, the next product number to be generated should be DOLE-IMSD-10-002. How do I do this?

Comment: query: "DOLE-IMSD-10-" this format is fixed or it will change as per product?

Comment: it is fixed sir.. the only characters that should change will be the last 3. and it should be counting like the sample I showed.

Comment: That seems pretty limited.  What happens when you get more than 999 pieces of equipment.  Maybe not today -- but one day.

Answer (score 0):

If "DOLE-IMSD-10-" is constant/fixed you can use primary key with auto increment and concatenate while displaying to user.

Even if it is not constant/fixed you can store "DOLE-IMSD-10-" this part in a different column and use primary key (with auto increment) column for storing incremental value. And while displaying to user/webpage you can concatenate and display.

Comment: you mean I need to make a different table only for the property number?

Comment: No, use a column in table.

Comment: is there no other way with this? I was planning to do something like this, I just dont know how to.

take all values in the property_number then take the last 3 characters, convert to int.
something like that..can you help me with this good sir?

Comment: What's wrong with Suresh's approach? If the database/table is in your control this is the way to go. I would really try to avoid letting the application handle stuff like this.